# WebAPI can't call Put method

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have the following code on server:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{

    public void Put(string filename, string description)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void Put()
    {
        ...
    }
```

and try to call it from client:

```
        var clientDescr = new HttpClient();

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("filename", "test"));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("description", "100"));

        HttpContent contentDescr = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        clientDescr.PutAsync("http://localhost:8758/api/upload", contentDescr).ContinueWith(
            (postTask) =>
            {
                postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            });
```

but this code calls second put method (without parameters). Why and how to call first put method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

You can either choose to pass the parameters in the query string, by just changing the URI to:

`http://localhost:8758/api/upload?filename=test&description=100`

or you can have Web API parse the form data for you by changing your action to look like this:

```
public void Put(FormDataCollection formData)
{
    string fileName = formData.Get("fileName");
    string description = formData.Get("description");
}
```

You can also choose to create a class that has a fileName and a description property and use that as your parameter and Web API should be able to bind it correctly for you.

Comment: thank you. Second question - how to call Delete method? I try to call clientDel.DeleteAsync("http://localhost:8758/api/upload?id=ttrtr").ContinueWith(...), but does not call public void Delete(int id)...

Comment: That should work just fine - it's possible the request isn't even reaching Web API